# 2011 Macbook Pro 15" Stuck on Black Screen & not responding to any key commands: no apple logo

Tags: macbook-pro

Was watching a video and screen went black. This has happened before but its usually a 5 second blink. This time it completely went black and did not respond to any commands.

I am able to shut off the computer but when booted you hear the machine noice but no chime and screen stays black.

Have tried basically all combination commands I can find.. (command+s, command+r, shift+command+alt+p+r)

Also tried typing in password and hitting enter but nothing... even tried shining the light through the apple logo to see if it showed the login box.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!